# Azure tables unable to store flattened JSON

Tags: json, azure-table-storage

I am using the npm `flat` package, and arrays/objects are flattened, but object/array keys are surrounded by '' , like in 'task_status.0.data' using the object below.

These specific fields do not get stored into AzureTables - other fields go through, but these are silently ignored. How would I fix this?

```
var obj1 = {
    "studentId": "abc",
    "task_status": [
            {
                "status":"Current",
                "date":516760078
            },
            {
                "status":"Late",
                "date":1516414446
            }
        ],
    "student_plan": "n"
 }
```

Here is how I am using it - simplified code example: Again, it successfully gets written to the table, but does not write the properties that were flattened (see further below):

```
var flatten = require('flat')
newObj1 = flatten(obj1);
var entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
newObj1.PartitionKey = entGen.String(uniqueIDFromMyDB);
newObj1.RowKey = entGen.String(uniqueStudentId);
tableService.insertEntity(myTableName, newObj1, myCallbackFunc);
```

In the above example, the flattened object would look like:

```
var obj1 = {
    studentId: "abc",
    'task_status.0.status': 'Current',
    'task_status.0.date': 516760078,
    'task_status.1.status': 'Late',
    'task_status.1.date': 516760078,
    student_plan: "n"
 }
```

Then I would add PartitionKey and RowKey.

all the `task_status` fields would silently fail to be inserted.

EDIT: This does not have anything to do with the actual flattening process - I just checked a perfectly good JSON object, with keys that had 'x.y.z' in it, i.e. AzureTables doesn't seem to accept these column names....which almost completely destroys the value proposition of storing schema-less data, without significant rework.

Comment: Can you share me the code?

Comment: I have added a more explicit example, which is a condensed version of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` in column name is not supported. You can [use a custom delimiter](https://github.com/hughsk/flat#delimiter) to flatten your objects instead.

For example:

```
newObj1 = flatten(obj1, {delimiter: '__'});
```

Comment: This should probably work, altho https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations says "." Is allowed. However it.has to be enclosed in back quotes. Am I right to say the npm flat package encloses in regular single quotes....and is there any way to change that instead?

Comment: I think the documentation you found is for Microsoft SQL Server, not for Azure Storage. As I test, It doesn't work to enclose column name in back quotes.

Comment: You can try the code in my above answer. It works for me.